# Browse people by location on Dailymile

Tags: geolocation, dailymile

I moved away from my hometown to a new state and city and would like to browse a certain location on [Dailymile](http://dailymile.com) to see if I can find anyone from my hometown or anyone I know. Is there a way to do this without changing my current residence in my profile?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was shutdown and no one can use it since several years ago.

Comment: Rest In Peace Dailymile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Community > People menu you can reach a search and recommendations page. On this page write a city name in the search text box and search. You can find some people according to their locaitons...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to search within the site by location.  How about creating a second account, perhaps using a different browser, just for the purposes of searching by your old hometown?  That way you can keep your current account intact.